# Is there an enchantment / effect /whatever to counter the sticky effect?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

Some mobs from mods, for example Witchery's Nightmare, and InfernalMobs with the Sticky modifier, make you drop your weapon (the nightmare even makes you drop armor, I think).

I know you can counteract the Nightmare with a Charm of Fanciful Thoughts, but my question is specifically targeted at InfernalMobs: Is there a way to counter the sticky modifier? Bonus if the answer also applies to other mods with a similar effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently no. If it's enabled in the config, the infernal mob has a fair chance of stealing whatever you use to attack them. This *really* stinks when it's something you spent a great deal of time to get the resources to build, and build.

The best strategy that I've found is to carry some cheaper weapons with good melee enchantments (sharpness, fire aspect, etc) and use *those* when you encounter infernal mobs. Strength potions are also very useful here.

Otherwise, a good strategy is:

[image: nope nope nope nope]

.. unless you've edited the config to make them drop more valuable stuff. All that work for *chainmail and some copper ingots*, ***seriously?***

Finally, if you *do* lose something and have death markers enabled, just die, grab something likely to kill whatever stole your stuff, and hurry back to kill it before it de-spawns. It will drop what it stole from you.

A side note, long-ranged attacks on infernal stuff with cheap bows in the nether generally yields *great* Tinker's Construct weapons other players thought they'd use to harvest some wither skulls :) Invisible ghasts, someone actually *made* them.

Long story short, edit the config to see what they drop prior to installing it, and carry some throw-away but *really* sharp stuff with some strength potions just in case. Fire resistance doesn't hurt, either.